# Run multiple python script in shell script

Tags: command-line, cron

I have four python scripts that needs to be run at background at the boot time. I have written a shell script where in it includes all the four python scripts

My shell script is as follows: `sudo nano launcher.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /

cd /home/pi/myfile

sudo python3 script1.py &

sudo python3 script2.py &

sudo python3 script3.py &

sudo python3 script4.py &

cd /
```

I have given the permission using `sudo chmod 777 launcher.sh`

After which i have scheduled the shell script using a crontab.

```
sudo crontab -e

@reboot  sh /home/pi/myfile/launcher.sh &

sudo reboot
```

My problem here is I could see that, only one script runs in spite of running all the four scripts at a time.

Kindly provide me the solution where I can run all the scripts at a time during the boot time.

Comment: If you've used `sudo crontab -e` to place your job in root's crontab, you don't need additional `sudo`s inside the script. As well, you shouldn't give it `777` permissions - that allows **anyone** to edit the script and potentially make it do something nefarious  - as root.

Comment: Yeah, start be removing `sudo` from the script. Never use `sudo` inside a script, except if it's an interactive script where you expect the user to be able to type their password.

Comment: Thank you so much for the support. The script is working absolutly fine.